# (405) Method Not Allowed. MVC app using WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to test an MVC application that uses WCF web service. It works fine when I run it using the dev server in VS2010. However when I deploy it on IIS7 and try to invoke any service method in my controller code I get the following error: 
(405) Method Not Allowed

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

My web config entries as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://SiteName/ServiceName/AuthenticationService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"
        contract="AuthService.IAuthenticationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: which are you deploying - the mvc app, wcf, or both?

Comment: Deploying both on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh...the WCF service and the MVC app had mismatched .NET versions! :( silly me.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the old "ASP.NET is not installed or register to your IIS" problemo Try registering it using

```
aspnet_regiis –i –enable
```

from a command prompt run under admin rights.